# How can I rewrite the jQuery plugin on Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm using the pagination on the page, when you click on the item pagination, I have shifted base frame, but I do not know how it is written on Angular

I have pagination component, code:

```js
app.component(function(storageService){

  storageService.model = this.model = {
    list: ["a", "b", "c"],
 pageNumber: 1,
 totalRows: 5,
  };

  this.openPagePagination = function(i){
        storageService.model.pageNumber = i;
  }

});
```

```html
<div>

<ul>
<li ng-repeat="el in model.list">{{el}}</li>
</ul>

<pagination processtype="model" />
</div>
```

```html
<ul class="pagination" 
    data-count="{{ $ctrl.processtype.totalRows }}" 
    ng-class="{'hide': !($ctrl.processtype.totalRows > 1)}"
    slidepagination>

  <li class="pagination-left waves-effect"
      ng-class="{ 'disabled' : ($ctrl.processtype.pageNumber == 1) ? 1 : 0 }">
    <a><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a>
  </li>
  
  <span class="pagination-block">
    <span class="pagination-full">
      
      <li ng-repeat=" i in [] | range:$ctrl.processtype.totalRows"
          ng-class="{'active': i == ($ctrl.processtype.pageNumber-1) }" 
          ng-click="$ctrl.processtype.openPagePagination(i+1)"
          class="pag-element"
          data-list="{{ i+1 }}">

        <a> {{ i+1 }} </a>
      </li>

    </span>
  </span>

  <li class="pagination-right waves-effect" 
      ng-class="{ 'disabled' : ($ctrl.processtype.pageNumber == $ctrl.processtype.totalRows) ? 1 : 0 }">
    <a><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But I do not know how to rewrite the animation on Angular

Because, now I have it:

```js
export default function (storageService) {
  let directive = {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: link
  }

  return directive;

  function link($scope, element, attrs) {
    console.log($scope);

    setTimeout(function(){

      let dLeft = $('.pagination-left');
      let dRight = $('.pagination-right');
      let Length = 0;

      $scope.state = 1;
      function initialState(){

          // обновляем пагинацию
          $('.pagination').find('.pagination-full').each(function(i, e){
            let el = $(e);
            let parent = el.parent().parent();
            let count = parseInt(parent.attr('data-count'));
            if (count) el.css('width', (count * $scope.widthFrame)  + 'px');
          });

          $('.pagination-full li').unbind("click").on("click", function(){

            if ($scope.state) {

              $scope.state = 0;
              let full = $(this).parent();
              let index = parseInt(full.parent().attr('data-pageindex')) || 1;
              let currentIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-list')) + 1;
              let frame = Math.abs(parseInt(full.css('margin-left')));

              frame = (currentIndex > 3) ? $scope.widthFrame * (currentIndex - $scope.showFrame) : 0;
              full.parent().attr('data-pageindex', currentIndex);
              full.animate({'margin-left': `-${frame}px`}, $scope.time, ()=>{
                $scope.state = 1;
                storageService.plugin.setTooltip();
              });

            }

          });

      } 

      setInterval(()=>{

        let count = $('.pagination li').length;
        if (Length != count) {
          initialState();
          Length = count;
        }

      }, 1000);

      // события левой клавиши
      dLeft.unbind("click").on("click", function(){
          let parent = $(this).parent();
          parent.find('.active').prev().click();
      });

      // события правой клавишы
      dRight.unbind("click").on("click", function(){
        let parent = $(this).parent();
        parent.find('.active').next().click();
      });


    }, 300);

  }
}
```

Comment: It looks more like a freelance job rather than a question.

Comment: @estus is right, you should give it a try writing by your self and come back when you face a concrete problem.